# Text output showing in next row in Shiny app UI

Tags: r, shiny

I am using below code to display `textOutput` next to header, but it's always showing in next row.

**Currently displaying:-**

```
GrandTotal:-

Display $ Value
```

**Expected to display**

```
GrandTotal:- Display $ Value
```

**Here is the code i am using.**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;",h3(style="color:blue;font-size:100%;","GrandTotal:-"),textOutput("Test"))
  )
server <- function(input,output) {

  output$Test <- renderText("Display $ Value")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both of them into `div` and add `block` style to both like so:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style="display: inline-block;width:80px;",h3(style="color:blue;font-size:100%;","GrandTotal:-")),
  div(style="display: inline-block;",textOutput("Test"))
)
server <- function(input,output) {
  output$Test <- renderText("Display $ Value")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]